# Changing UITableViewCell height using tableView.beginUpdates()

Tags: ios, uitableview

SO I want to change the height of my UITableViewCell by doing something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        return 140
    } else {
        return 90
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that when I do this, the cell "expands" slower than the content of expanded portion shows, so whatever is in the expanded portion shows before the cell fully expands and it is kind of ugly. This problem can be fixed if I use `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`, but I don't want to reload the cell because I have a timer displayed in the expanded portion of the cell.